# Accessing array elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, d3.js

I want the user to be able to draw a line on an SVG canvas. At first, a "rough path" consisting of 1px by 1px rectangles is shown, then when the user releases the mouse, the line he traced is converted into a SVG `<path>`. This is the code that creates the rectangles:

```
var svg = d3.select('#svg-overlay'); //SVG Canvas
var roughPath = [];
( ... )
var tx = Math.round(e.pageX - offset.left);
var ty = Math.round(e.pageY - offset.top);

roughPath.push(svg.append('rect')
    .attr('width', 1)
    .attr('height', 1)
    .attr('x', tx)
    .attr('y', ty)
    .attr('fill', 'white'));
```

After the path has been drawn and converted into `<path>`, I want to be able to remove all the rectangles stored in `roughPath`. However, I can't figure out how to reach the elements inside that array. `d3.select(roughPath)` didn't work, neither did `d3.select(roughPath).selectAll('rect')`, nor `roughPath.forEach(...)`. Could someone pitch in a suggestion how I could reach d3 elements stored within an array, or at least how I could remove all elements within `roughPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to hold on to additional references to selections in your own structures (such as your `roughPath` array). Instead, think of the DOM as a collection of nodes (rects, in your case) that you can query using selectors.

If you add a class to the nodes you create on your rough path you can use that to query the group of nodes:

```
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'roughpath')
    .attr('width', 1)
    .attr('height', 1)
    .attr('x', tx)
    .attr('y', ty)
    .attr('fill', 'white');
```

Later, when you want to delete the nodes you can simply do:

```
svg.selectAll('rect.roughpath').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott! I originally wanted to do that as well, but, being used to C++ and pointers, I figured the "right" way would be to treat those arrays as pointer arrays and do all my work from there. Glad to hear it's not bad style to do it with class/id :)

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer is the most idiomatic way of doing what you're trying. If you really want to store the references in an array though, removing them is pretty simple:

```
roughPath.forEach(function(d){ d.remove(); })
```